# JavaScript - send form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to collect form data and send it as a payload in my POST request in my ReactJS component like this:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    event.preventDefault();
    // There is a promise with XMLHttpRequest
}

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="registration-block">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                // There are some inputs and submit button
                </form>
            </div>
            {popup}
        </div>
    );
```

As you could see I created a function handleSubmit which I call in onSubmit event

In this function the construction `new FormData(event.target);` returns empty form

What is the right way to collect data from my form and send it as payload to POST request?

Comment: can you please explain little more or post more code and why are you sending formData instead of setting in state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of reactjs [reactjs forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {fname:'', lname:''};
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    let val = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: val });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            value={this.state.fname}
            name="fname"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter fname"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            value={this.state.lname}
            type="text"
            name="lname"
            placeholder="Enter lname"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful info. It helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will want to maintain the form state in React rather than in the form itself.

See the following docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.

A working example looks like:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.target);

        fetch('/api/form-submit-url', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
        });
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

try changing the code like this.

```
<form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
  // There are some inputs and submit button
</form>
```